# Mongo is it possible to increment array element if not present

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I am trying to increment an element inside an array as below

```
{ "_id" : 1
  "myarray": [
    {"a": 1}
    {"b": 1}
    {"c": 1}
  ]
}

{ "_id" : 2
  "myarray": [
    {"a": 4}
    {"b": 7}
    {"c": 9}
  ]
}

db.mycollection({"_id": 1}, {"$inc": {"myarray.$.a"}});
db.mycollection({"_id": 2}, {"$inc": {"myarray.$.b"}});
```

I am aware of the mongo [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator for identifying an element in array as used above.

The problem I am tackling is in some scenarios of my data does not have the array

```
{ "_id" : 3
}

{ "_id" : 4
}
```

and if I execute `db.mycollection({"_id": 3}, {"$inc": {"myarray.$.a"}});` It does not update the document with id since **myarray** does not exist the doc.

so the immediate fix I made was to initialize **myarray** to be zero whenever I insert a doc

```
{ "_id" : 3
  "myarray": [
    {"a": 0}
    {"b": 0}
    {"c": 0}
  ]
}
{ "_id" : 4
  "myarray": [
    {"a": 0}
    {"b": 0}
    {"c": 0}
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to directly update with pre-initializing the array element with zero?

Answer (score 0):

`db.mycollection({"_id": 1}, {"$inc": {"myarray.$.a"}});` is wrong in so many ways:

- First of all it is `db.mycollection.update` or updateOne, updateMany etc.
- Next, [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/index.html) requires a number on how much you want to increment. If it is 1, you have to specify it explicitly:  `{"$inc": {"myarray.$.a": 1}}`
- Finally, the `$` operator you are aware of requires a match from the query part (the first argument of the `update*` functions). Please read the page you are referring to in your question.

To answer the question - no, there is no such way. It's not about the `$inc` - it actually initialises a field with 0 if it doesn't exists. It's `$` that doesn't push a new element into array because the document won't pass the filter stage where you specify which matching subdocument should `$` refer to.